# GAE Cloud Endpoints custom API public api key issues

Tags: google-app-engine

I've exposed a few APIs using `go-endpoints`. The APIs work fine, but what I'd like to do is restrict usage of the APIs to only a few referers. Since I'm not passing any authentication information, I do not need OAuth (actually, I really do not want to use OAuth as I expect anonymous users to utilize a front-end that uses this API... I just want that front-end and perhaps another one to use my API).

Apparently the way to do this is to make a Public API Key using the Google Developers Console (Project --> APIs and auth --> Credentials --> Create new Key).

I've changed my JavaScript to use this key, by passing it as a param: `https://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/myService/v1/doSomething?key=key_from_developer_console`

However, when I make the call, I get a 403 back with this error:
`"Access Not Configured. The API () is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."`

Well, initially I set the referer to `my-app-id.appspot.com/*`, which is only place I want my API to be used from. So I figured I'd remove it just to see, but I get the same issue.

There are some old posts here about having to enable Contacts API and Google + API. I tried that, and it didn't work either.

So what gives? There is virtually no documentation from Google on this Public API Key feature. This is really driving me up a wall...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem yesterday. I decided to generate my own key and added in my own logic to check for the 'key' param from the request. I just added the self-generated key to my env_variables and it works. However, if you try to redeploy after taking this approach, you may still see the access configuration issues..at least I have still.

Comment: @SimplicityGuy Update: I generate my own token and attach it to the request URL as a 'token' parameter. If you add it as a 'key' parameter, it somehow automatically triggers Google App Engine to check for authorization. This is the only workaround that I got to work.